# How to submit a pyspark job to remote cluster from windows client?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

We are using a remote Spark cluster with YARN (in Hortonworks). Developers want to use Spyder to implement Spark application in Windows. To ssh to cluster using ipython notebook or Jupyter works well. Is there any other way to communicate with Spark cluster from Windows.

Question 1: I got a headache with submitting spark job(written in python) from Windows which has no Spark installed. Is there anyone could help me out of this. Specifically, how to phrase the command line to submit the job.

We could ssh to YARN node in the cluster just in case these might relative to some solution. It is also ping-able from cluster to windows client.

Question 2: What do we need to have in the client side e.g. Spark libraries if we want to do the debug with environment like this?